# Grep a whole whitespace-separated word in bash

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep

Say I have this data:

```
hi helo tmp#100000 bye
100000 hi bye
hi 100000 bye
```

And 100000 is in variable: $var
I want to grep 100000 only as a whole word, desired output:

```
100000 hi bye
hi 100000 bye
```

I have tried everything that ever been answered in StuckOverflow and nothing seem to work:
`grep "\b$var\b", grep -E "[[:blank:]]$var[[:blank:]]"` and many many more.
I think the problem, might be in `#`.
The solution needs to work for a case where the variable equal: `hi.*bye` as a Regex as well.

Please help

Comment: Use `grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])$var($|[[:blank:]])"`

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: `grep -Fw "$var"` or `grep -P "\\b$var\\b"` would work **_except_** that `#` is not a "word character", therefore the word boundary matches between `#` and `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])$var($|[[:blank:]])"
```

Or, assuming it is a GNU `grep` (as [suggested by Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249030/grep-a-whole-whitespace-separated-word-in-bash/64249109?noredirect=1#comment113613747_64249109)):

```
grep -P '(?<!\S)\Q'"$var"'\E(?!\S)'
```

Choose the second one in case your `$var` contains a *literal text* to search for *and* `$var` can hold values containing special regex metacharacters like `(`, `)`, `[`, `{`, `+`, `^`, etc., see [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078)
See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/QI5xR0):

```sh
s='hi helo tmp#100000 bye
100000 hi bye
hi 100000 bye'
var=100000
grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])$var($|[[:blank:]])" <<< "$s"
# => 100000 hi bye
#    hi 100000 bye
```

Here,

- `-E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax, `-P` enables a PCRE syntax
- `(^|[[:blank:]])` - matches either start of input or a horizontal whitespace
- `(?<!\S)\Q` - `(?<!\S)` checks if the char immediately on the left is a whitespace or start of string and `\Q` starts quoting the pattern, the `$var` will be parsed as a literal text
- `$var` - the `var` contents
- `($|[[:blank:]])`  - matches either end of input or a horizontal whitespace.
- `\E(?!\S)` - `\E` stops quoting and `(?!\S)` requires either a whitespace or end of string immediately on the right.

Comment: The PCRE expression: `grep -P '(^|\s)\Q'"$var"'\E(\s|$)'` -- perhaps a little more readable. That also matches the var as plain test, not a regex, due to \Q...\E

Comment: @glennjackman That is good in case 1) if OP has a GNU `grep` and 2) if `var` can have values other than just numbers.

Comment: Thanks that's working for the example I gave, but could you tell me why it doesn't work with var="hi.*by" (regex) ?

Comment: @jenny `hi.*by` is a regex pattern, right? Your  lines do not end with `by`, they end with `bye`, see https://ideone.com/MjNQNx with `var='hi.*bye'`

Answer (score 6):

Non-regex search using `awk`:

```
awk -v var="$var" '
{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == var) {print; break}}' file
```

```
100000 hi bye
hi 100000 bye
```

Otherwise a shorter awk using custom `FS`:

```
awk -F "(^|[[:blank:]])$var([[:blank:]]|$)" 'NF > 1' file
```